# Potential extension of internship

Tags: internship

I was initially offered a 2-month internship with a firm, when I only intended to apply for a one-month internship. This was my fault as I didn't specify the one-month duration in my application. When I received the offer, I replied requesting for the internship to be shortened, saying that wanted to give others a chance at interning at the firm as well. My request was granted. However I am now considering extending the internship, since I have some spare time.

Question: If I ask for an extension during my internship in this situation, will it look bad on me?

Comment: Can you edit your post to make the specific question more obvious? Do you want people to tell you whether or not they think it will look bad on you? Are you wondering if you should even ask at all? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until you're in the job for a while before considering if you want to extend or not.

If you ask before you start, and it gets extended, it's going to look strange if you subsequently ask for it to be shortened again if you find you don't like it too much.

See what you think of the placement before asking for another extension/shortening.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer because we don't really know the culture of the organization you're working for or the specifics of the internship program you're a part of. That said, it does sound like the employer has some degree of flexibility since they already granted you a request to change the length of the internship. If you are planning on asking and want to try to reduce the chances it's perceived poorly, you can try to tailor your request:

- Certainly don't mention that you're asking because you "have some spare time," that just makes it sound like you're not actively planning your career path and haven't been able to secure any other employment or educational opportunities
- Point out projects you've been working on and how they would benefit from your continued involvement
- If the internship has an explicit "learning" component (ie you're supposed to be gaining specific skills as a part of an educational degree program) point out how you could continue to develop certain skills as a part of the extension
- You initially mentioned that you wanted to "give others a chance." Can you now explain how your request for an extension would or would not void that goal? If they were able to bring in another intern, could you mentor or work with that person?